# Event result parameters and arguments in console

Tags: contract-development, web3js, events, javascript

I read about using events from this source http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events
I used a simple multiply contract:

```
contract test1{
    uint a;
    event event_res(string msg,uint x);
      function test1(){
          a = 1;
      }
      function multiply (uint b){
          a = a*b;
        event_res("the value after multiplying is:",a); 
      }
      function getval()  returns(uint){
          return a;
      }
}
```

and executed sendtransaction as:

```
var testing = web3.eth.contract(interface).at(address);
var event = testing.event_res(function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.args);
    else
        console.log(error);
});
var result = testing.multiply.sendTransaction(5,{from : web3.eth.coinbase},function(err,result){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

I got multiple parameters as output in console as following:

```
{ msg: 'the value after multiplying is:',
  x: { [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] } }
```

Can anyone tell me what these parameters(s,e and c) are and what they mean?

Comment: for more details you could check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24416/web3-javascript-api-transaction-object-not-matching-documentation/24432#24432

Answer (score 4):

`result.args` is an object with 2 keys, `msg` and `x` as you've declared in your `event_res`.

`x` is a **[BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) object** that is stringified to `{ [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] }`.  You can use BigNumber methods, like `results.args.x.toNumber()` to see it better.

EDIT: Following was added to the question

> Can anyone tell me what these parameters(s,e and c) are and what they
>   mean?

Those are properties of the [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) object. It's out of scope here to go into the internals of a general external library like BigNumber.

The main thing that helps is to **recognize that when you get an object that looks like it, is that it's probably a BigNumber** and you can call methods on it, as well as perform other additional BigNumber operations (without needing to know its internals).

Comment: i would also like to know what arguments s,e and c []  mean?

Comment: I see the question has been edited, so I've edited the answer too. They are internals of BigNumber, which are not necessary to be familiar with, just like you can use web3.js without needing to know what `console.log(web3)` means.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to the community! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the big checkbox.