# Event result documentation

Tags: events

The current [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#additional-resources-for-understanding-events) does not go into detail about the structure of the result returned by an event. In [this](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3243/events-in-solidity-using-blockchain-as-eventstore) thread and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/event-result-parameters-and-arguments-in-console) question, there are mentions about the fields of the **result** returned by an event listener but where is the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [JavaScript-API - web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter):

- `Object` - When using manual filter options, it returns a log object as follows:

  - `logIndex`: `Number` - integer of the log index position in the block. null when its pending log.
  - `transactionIndex`: `Number` - integer of the transactions index position log was created from. null when its pending log.
  - `transactionHash`: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the transactions this log was created from. null when its pending log.
  - `blockHash`: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this log was in. null when its pending. null when its pending log.
  - `blockNumber`: Number - the block number where this log was in. null when its pending. null when its pending log.
  - `address`: String, 32 Bytes - address from which this log originated.
  - `data`: String - contains one or more 32 Bytes non-indexed arguments of the log.
  - `topics`: Array of Strings - Array of 0 to 4 32 Bytes DATA of indexed log arguments. (In solidity: The first topic is the hash of the signature of the event (e.g. Deposit(address,bytes32,uint256)), except if you declared the event with the anonymous specifier.)

---

#### An Example Of A `TheDAO.CreatedToken` Event

Use the following `geth` commands to extract some `CreatedToken` events:

```
var theDAOABIFragment = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"}, {"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"CreatedToken","type":"event"}, {"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
var theDAO = web3.eth.contract(theDAOABIFragment).at(theDAOAddress);
var theDAOCreatedTokenEvent = theDAO.CreatedToken({}, {fromBlock: 1428757, toBlock: 1429757});
theDAOCreatedTokenEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

And here are the first two events

> {"address":"0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413","args":{"amount":"30000000000000000","to":"0xb504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211"},"blockHash":"0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f","blockNumber":1429038,"event":"CreatedToken","logIndex":3,"transactionHash":"0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1","transactionIndex":9}
>   {"address":"0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413","args":{"amount":"500000000000000000","to":"0x53024f875bc85709af41d1c65c01fb4cc92d5c1c"},"blockHash":"0x48cf967fc94c2f808d82906c1a56e3e09abc99bb8279266fbace13963dc30a1f","blockNumber":1429053,"event":"CreatedToken","logIndex":0,"transactionHash":"0x1e9ec3974b89653961cbd996d4f6cfc2845db977a3385761b99ed459c2464740","transactionIndex":1}

And from [TheDAO's source code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code), here is the definition of the `CreatedToken` event:

```
event CreatedToken(address indexed to, uint amount);
```

So looking at the first record from the results we have:

- **address**: "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413" - The DAO's address
- **args** - `CreatedToken`'s arguments

  - **amount**: "30000000000000000"
  - **to**: "0xb504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211"
- **blockHash**: "0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f" - hash of the block containing the event
- **blockNumber**: [1429038](https://etherscan.io/block/1429038) - number of the block containing the event
- **event**: CreatedToken - Event name
- **logIndex**: 3
- **transactionHash**: "[0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1)"
- **transactionIndex**: 9

Getting the transactions `getTransactionReceipt(...)`, you can see the same event data in the `logs` data structure:

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1")
{
  blockHash: "0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f",
  blockNumber: 1429038,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 284538,
  from: "0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98",
  gasUsed: 91206,
  logs: [{
      address: "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",
      blockHash: "0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f",
      blockNumber: 1429038,
      data: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006a94d74f430000",
      logIndex: 3,
      topics: ["0xdbccb92686efceafb9bb7e0394df7f58f71b954061b81afb57109bf247d3d75a", "0x000000000000000000000000b504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211"],
      transactionHash: "0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1",
      transactionIndex: 9
  }],
  root: "e8ba75bf5d12f93c991721565270a135194887b9260b3f7d809d9a6270dcd6c5",
  to: "0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",
  transactionHash: "0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1",
  transactionIndex: 9
}
```

Getting the block's data, you can see that **blockHash** above is the same as **hash** below:

```
> eth.getBlock(1429038);
{
  difficulty: 32654434227321,
  extraData: "0xd783010306844765746887676f312e352e31856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 368538,
  hash: "0x031d5bac6154ca7616ac62e966da2b50a0aaa1b3bc24958ed9cb52d8c8fc1e2f",
  logsBloom: "0x00400000000000020000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000001002000000000000000005000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000",
  miner: "0x2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d164135398226",
  nonce: "0x1ec6b2f3920a1b75",
  number: 1429038,
  parentHash: "0xb70be7a89e89a93248498c60e0254f7212bdec42ec5f3be3e9c4687c46a8dd21",
  receiptRoot: "0x0c80b60072f41ffe060af09913c09e8760839e084b1711663b6c05e5b5b4a698",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 2144,
  stateRoot: "0x1b7a7df358c82b30a2e84e10bde606af1a1e868bde1abf499518f5282b4c2caa",
  timestamp: 1461984747,
  totalDifficulty: 16452703203387523239,
  transactions: ["0x07233561a800dcd2d0b7f5b913f689d15418264f3c025959a04c6a06fc83a715", "0x7d62d8988352db1bef3d2814c80bd78c0789e0345bb5a71bb4b61595e0f2c490", "0xebf630e4bdc04eeebfac6283ca208ed49d80c4ae3340cb6f15df050fc8c1e4ef", "0xa60119d8f8078b862e8df96877f9846d68ba89798be0510b7cf8593eb2f80bc4", "0xbc9850758015bf24e115a0d019001972259b58a562f3664e03df71f709e6cff5", "0xc271d871f5becd2e00b0bd6e1460e7f77812b985ae5de79a0e0f3bfc9ee4f82d", "0xada6df7c55113ddda794ba9924245e4c2b3ff9a7a61d00477976df28910961f6", "0x222b83cac7b441eea0b769268b9534167295065b11b62ad4c3b80c17384ae4da", "0xa3c3bcdb89da86c6b7d174ccb375702c32fb9bfc662d5281436d0da7bb66630f", "0xc96b0f95a1e7e8c07cd488a05f20f9e8d4003fe8eea0ec7f7f4bf199af3198e1", "0xa8ae7985e399753bcc8fd9b92a6a2af206c1b9e813412a337a0c073d3d25ef05", "0xea513060036eb3128e1b9a0d0d434a51b63c9fa45a8048961a766231f7e6ab03", "0x81fc3f258042fc69b11970e632e7fbbb4bbaae1fa52facde2cdd8d76d46fb8e4", "0x6e806f8ecd9b511d560819219e8fb11cf47cb7d9ad643574fb121687d89d175b"],
  transactionsRoot: "0x15fb5d46063445c898589e3894c1002eecac98fdecf6d4ae6c82c78a03ce9390",
  uncles: []
}
```

Let's work out the data field from the `getTransactionReceipt(...)` result:

```
data: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006a94d74f430000"
```

This is the unindexed parameter to the `CreatedToken` event:

```
> web3.toBigNumber("0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006a94d74f430000")
30000000000000000
```

And let's work out the topics from the `getTransactionReceipt(...)` result:

```
topics: ["0xdbccb92686efceafb9bb7e0394df7f58f71b954061b81afb57109bf247d3d75a", "0x000000000000000000000000b504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211"],
```

The first element `"0xdbccb92686efceafb9bb7e0394df7f58f71b954061b81afb57109bf247d3d75a"` is the signature of the event:

```
> web3.sha3('CreatedToken(address,uint256)')
"0xdbccb92686efceafb9bb7e0394df7f58f71b954061b81afb57109bf247d3d75a"
```

The second element `"0x000000000000000000000000b504e60998c6f354a0794abd91d85e8bc8436211"` is the indexed **to** address parameter.

From [github - go-ethereum/core/vm/log.go, lines 67-80](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/log.go#L67-L80):

```
func (r *Log) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "address":          r.Address,
        "data":             fmt.Sprintf("%#x", r.Data),
        "blockNumber":      fmt.Sprintf("%#x", r.BlockNumber),
        "logIndex":         fmt.Sprintf("%#x", r.Index),
        "blockHash":        r.BlockHash,
        "transactionHash":  r.TxHash,
        "transactionIndex": fmt.Sprintf("%#x", r.TxIndex),
        "topics":           r.Topics,
    }

    return json.Marshal(fields)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes me wonder if storing data inside contracts is even necessary. Do you know if logs are permanent to the block chain or are they pruned after a while?

Comment: You can't access the logs data from within a contract, but if it is just to read from outside the VM then just the logs will do. When you sync your blockchain with `--fast`, you lose the ability to call `debug.traceTransaction(...)`, but the logs data will still be in the blockchain.

Comment: I knew about the logs not being accessible to contracts (even to the contract that generated them) but I'm not sure if they can be pruned away or if there are any plans of removing them in future versions of the block chain?

Comment: That's a good new question to be asked in this site. I've only found http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-is-the-difference-of-a-pruned-and-an-unpruned-blockchain .

Comment: Do you know of a way to contact the devs. I've tried on github but I couldn't get an answer. I'll also try twitter.

Comment: @Sebi Yes, logs are permanent to the blockchain.  It's a different question and answered here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/are-events-permanently-stored-and-reliably-available-to-contracts-in-the-future