# Events called in constructor function

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, constructor

how to watch events in web3.js when the event is fired from inside the constructor functionof a contract? Eg:

```
contract A{
   event Invoked(string);
   function A(){
   Invoked("constructor invoked!");
   }
 }
```

what to write in web3.js layer to get the output of event in the console.

Comment: Full example to extract events and interpreting the data at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/event-result-documentation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-29 `fromBlock` is `"latest"` by default. So in the case of an event sent in the constructor, `"latest"` may miss your event.

Try setting `fromBlock` to an earlier numerical value. At worst, try `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the snippet in the [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#additional-resources-for-understanding-events):

```
var abi = /* abi as generated by the compiler */;
var ClientReceipt = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var clientReceipt = ClientReceipt.at(0x123 /* address */);

var event = clientReceipt.Deposit();

// watch for changes
event.watch(function(error, result){
    // result will contain various information
    // including the argumets given to the Deposit
    // call.
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});

// Or pass a callback to start watching immediately
var event = clientReceipt.Deposit(function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```

Use one of the listeners and change the event name and functionality.